# ReFS combination with storage spaces and TrueCrypt

Tags: windows-8.1, ntfs, truecrypt, storage-spaces, refs

I would like to store data encrypted and reliable (no bit rot, mirror).
Already did some testing but I am not sure at some points.

For all cases: I set up a windows storage space with 2 drives (mirror setup). And now ...

case 1
format drive with ReFS, activate bitlocker, create file-volume-truecrypt, format that with ReFS
-> poor performance, not acceptable

case 2
format drive with ReFS, activate bitlocker, create file-volume-truecrypt, format that with NTFS
-> poor performance, not acceptable

case 3
format drive with NTFS, activate bitlocker, create file-volume-truecrypt, format that with ReFS
-> good performance, reliability? (*)

case 4
format drive with truecrypt (full disk encryption), format it with ReFS
-> good performance, reliability?, no bitlocker possible (**)

(*) question: in this setup will the storage space detect and repair bit rots? Or to put it in other words: Does the "inner" ReFS has any advantage at all if the outer environment is NTFS?

(**) question: does the TC-layer prevent the storage-space+ReFS feature of repairing bitrots? This would be very interesting to get information on.

This may looks very paranoid but I would like to have bitlocker+truecrypt just in case. If (*) defeats bit rotting I just found my ideal solution since performance is good. If not I would rather use (**), again, if it would defeat bit rotting.
Case 1+2 without bitlocker leads to same performance. It's just an performance issue if I have a single huge container in an ReFS environment.

Thanks for any help and external links.

Comment: Storage Spaces is RAID, there are several options, none of them will repair bit rot but one will make it irrelevant due to parity and mirroring

Comment: Thanks, but I think your statement is only true in combination with NTFS.
"To combat bit rot, ReFS (again, when combined with Storage Spaces) uses its "scrubbing" feature to read all copies of a file in the array and compare their metadata with one another. If a corrupted file is found anywhere in the array, it is replaced by a good copy" [link](http://www.anandtech.com/show/5433/microsofts-refs-filesystem-for-windows-8-server-explained)

Comment: Storage Spaces is still software-ish RAID feature.  What file system you use won't change the features of Storage Spaces

Comment: Yes, but afaik using storage spaces changes the features of ReFS. Still, those two questions ( * )  and ( ** ) are, what I am concerned about.